# Chuppa and Kedushin Course by Chabad/Rabbanut

Tags: marriage

I have read and heard that the Central Committee of Chabad offers a course in the laws of Chuppa and Kedushin, with tests from the Rabbanut.

Does anyone know anything about this course as I would love to learn this material.

Comment: Like with everything you have to contact them. If this is the committee you were talking about https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=41311

Comment: IDK if this is it... there is no number there!

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/118201/jewish/Vaad-Rabonei-Lubavitch.htm

Comment: not in service )-;

Comment: Try 718-604-1839, I’ll keep looking. Let me know if this one works.